# how to have multiple css bundle in svelte with SCSS

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Traditionally if I have external scss files (*global1.scss, global2.scss*) in svelte, I would import them inside App.svelte like below code, and at the end, all external scss files will be merged into *bundle.css*

```
//App.svelte
...
<style>
  :global {
     import "styles/global1"; //will import global1.scss
     import "styles/global2"; //will import global1.scss
  }
</style>
```

---

However, I have sightly different requirement for my app. Instead of all scss being merged into same css file, I want a new bundle for each external scss file like so:

```
bundle.css // for component styles
global1.css //for global1.scss
global2.css //for global2.scss
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with the global stylesheets being combined into one global stylesheet, you can use [rollup-plugin-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-scss).  The plugin doesn't seem to support outputting a stylesheet per imported file.

First, import your global scss files in your entrypoint (`main.js`).

```
import App from './App.svelte';
import './style1.scss';
import './style2.scss';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body
});

export default app;
```

Then add `rollup-plugin-scss` to your config to handle the scss imports. It will take all imported scss files and output them to `global.css`.

```
// rollup.config.js
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';

export default {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        // ...
        scss({
            output: 'public/build/global.css',
            include: ['/**/*.scss'] // do not include Svelte-generated *.css files
        }),

    ],
    // ...
};
```

This config will output `global.css` to your `public/build` directory. `bundle.css` should still be generated from the Svelte compilation.

Comment: It creates the style1.css but the content inside those is still scss. None of the variables have been removed. Can you pls advice

Comment: I didn't realize that styleNodes contained the unprocessed CSS. It doesn't look like the plugin supports outputting separate CSS files. I've updated my answer to show how to generate one global.css file for global stylesheets and a bundle.css for component styles.